# php adding a text box upon checkbox checked does not post

Tags: javascript, php, input, getelementbyid

I have code that adds input text when the box is checked and it shows up but getting the value from the code does not work.  Here is my code:

```
<input name=ship[] type=checkbox value=example id=Ex>Application Model Example
<span id='Location'>& nbsp;</span>

var checkbox = document.getElementById('Ex');
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
if (document.getElementById('modelType')) {
    document.getElementById('modelType').remove();
} else {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.name = 'modelType';
      input.id = 'modelType';
      input.type = 'text';
      input.placeholder = 'Model Type';
      input.required;
      document.body.appendChild(input);
      var foo = document.getElementById('Location');
      foo.appendChild(input);
}
});

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
echo "Model Type is $modelType";
}
```

The text input only appears after I click the checkbox which is exactly what I want, but when I go to get the value in the text input in POST is never appears?  Also it would be nice if the text input was required, but input.required; does not work (that was just a guess)

Comment: You should put attribute values in quotation marks. They aren't required in every case, but they make the code cleaner, easier to read, and more maintainable.

Comment: Apart from @MarcB's answer, do you have a form surrounding your code that has `method="post"`?

Comment: yes <form action="http://wiki1.example.com/EventForm.php" method=post> and everything works (there is more to the form) except I cannot get the value of the input field added by javascript.  All the other one work.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using PHP properly. It has not for a LONG time now auto-created variables for you based on form-inputs. This is a GOOD thing. `register_globals` is dead, gone, and gloriously so.

Your code should be

```
echo "Model Type is {$_POST['modelType']}";
```

Comment: Right thanks,  The echo isn't the problem, even when I change it to get instead of post modelType does not appear in the url.  Using post and the code above it does the exact same thing.  $modelType is not defined.   Also above that code I have a if (isset($_POST['modelType'])) {
        $modelType=$_POST['modelType'];
}